# tools for coloring command line output of "dict"?

Tags: shell, colors

is there an existing solution somewhere to color the output of [dict](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dict) to improve its readability?  I know i could manually color the output using `tput`, but i hope for a better solution.

(i don't want to use it in a GUI)

Comment: I recommend [lolcat](https://github.com/busyloop/lolcat). It will sure make output of any command [very colorful](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/busyloop/lolcat/master/ass/screenshot.png).

Comment: o.O thanks for the hint, but that doesn't improve the readability very much :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `colorit` which should be shipped together with `dict`. Usage example:

```
dict <word> | colorit
```